# Захват экрана из контейнера Docker

Tags: python, docker

Стоит задача написать на Python программу, функционал которой подразумевает запись экрана. По ряду причин мною было принято решение упаковать проект в докер. В связи с этим встает вопрос: есть ли возможность записывать экран прямо из контейнера? Если да, возможно ли при этом добиться кроссплатформенности? Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097837/capture-video-data-from-screen-in-python

Comment: *По ряду причин мною было принято решение упаковать проект в докер* — напрасно. этим вы усложнили задачу на несколько порядков.